# Using path.join in Node.js to require a specific module

Tags: node.js, path, backslash

I'm generating .js files using a specific template.
The paths to the modules to require are passed as params to the template.
Before passing them to the template the paths are created using path.join.

```
example:
var path = path.join(process.cwd(), 'location/to/module');
template(path);

in the template file:
var result = '/'use strict/';'
    result += 'var testcase = require(' + path + ')';
```

When the file is generated the path inside require looks like this:

```
require('D:\rootdirectory\directory\deleteCookies.test.js');
```

The backslashes in the path are causing problems.

Can anyone help me, thank you!!

Comment: Are you using linux or windows, cause it seems ok for windows ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by escaping the backslashes using the jsesc module.

```
var jsesc = require('jsesc');

result += 'var testcase = require(' + jsesc(path) + ')';
```

The output:

```
require('D:\\rootdirectory\\directory\\deleteCookies.test.js');
```